# How to stop ringing alarm in Java?

Tags: java, android

I followed a YouTube guide to get going on an alarm clock app. It seems to be working well, however when the alarm starts to play and I click the button to stop the alarm it does not stop the ringtone service. I've tried looking at other stack overflow questions but could not find a logical answer for myself. I know that my intents are not triggering the ringtone service in the receiver class to stop. Anyone have an idea how to stop the ring tone service from a mainactivityclass and send the trigger to the receiver class?

Mainactivity code to trigger alarm and play ringtone

```
public void setTimer(View v){
        //Make alarmmanager
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal_now.setTime(currentTime);
        cal_alarm.setTime(currentTime);

        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,mHour);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,mMin);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        if (cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){
            cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }
        //Add alarm to ArrayList
        Alarms.add(cal_alarm);
        showAlarm();

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, i, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

    //Stop Alarm
    public void cancelAlarm(View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        alarmview.setText("Alarm cancelled");
    }
```

Receiver class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Set vibration
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(3000);

        //Make notification for alarm
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("WakeMeYup").setContentText("Wake up!").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build();

        //Pass notification to Android system
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        manager.notify(0, notification);

        //Play ringtone
        Uri notificati = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notificati);
        r.play();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a Ringtone class, which receives an int that decides whether it should play or stop the alarm. The onclick listeners put an extra message into the intent which is picked up by the ringtone class and reads them so it knows which bit of code to run.